# Sound barrier in addition to moisture barrier for engineered hardwood flooring

Tags: hardwood-floor

The mfg. of my 1/2" engineered flooring recommends 15# felt moisture barrier, which I have and intend on using over my 3/4" t/g std. sub-flooring to which I have added 1/4" plywood underlayment (screwed down) for a smoother and more solid flooring.  I recently have read about sound barriers in addition to the moisture barrier.  My home is a stand alone single family home with a standard cement foundation and crawl space.  Do I need a sound barrier and if so why and what do you recommend?

Thanks,

Douglas Nicholson (member)

Comment: Are you worried about squirrels living in your crawl space will find your new floor too noisy?